# touchesMoved drag on UIImage after CGAffineTransformRotate Causes image to spin off screen

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, cgaffinetransform

I'm not sure why after calling this CGAffineTransform method on a UIImageView and then trying to drag it, causes it to spin out of view. Any help is appreciated.

```
- (void)setRotation:(Float32)rotation {
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0,0.0);
transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, degreesToRadians(rotation));
[self setTransform:transform];
}

- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {

CGPoint pt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
CGRect frame = [self frame];

frame.origin.x += pt.x - startLocation.x;
frame.origin.y += pt.y - startLocation.y;

[self setFrame:frame];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the `transform` property is anything other than the identity, the `frame` property is undefined. You should not read from it or write to it. Instead you should use the `center` and `bounds` properties.

Also in your `-setRotation`, the first 2 lines are useless. The first line assigns a value, which is then overwritten by the second line. The second line's net effect is to assign the identity back to the variable (a translation of 0, 0 is nothing). The method could instead just be

```
self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadians(rotation));
```

Comment: Kevin, Im not quite understanding your instructions to use the center and bounds properties. Would you be able to provide an example of what you are referring to specifically about using bounds? I've tried using the center property as you suggest to set the position of my UIImageView, but that causes it to flicker and jump all over when dragging.

Comment: The `frame` property is calculated using the `center` and `bounds` properties. Those two properties are the "true" indicators of view size and position. `frame` represents the bounds of the view in the coordinate space of its superview. However if the `transform` property is something other than the identity, then `frame` is no longer true. In fact, `frame` tries to apply the transform, but transforms can produce non-rectangular shapes, which is why `frame` ends up undefined. In your case with a rotation, this is definitely true.